# Spring-ws SOAP 404 error

Tags: spring, soap, spring-ws, soapui

i did a tutorial after this -> http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-ws-how
when i go to url http://localhost:8080/myService/services/MemberDetailsRequest.wsdl , i get the static wsdl file.. but when i use SoapUI to import in the wsdl file and then test it.. i only get 404 error, any1 has a solution to that?

any suggestions, why i can't get any responses with soapUI?

Comment: At the bottom of the SoapUI screen you will find a series of buttons, one is called `error log`. It will provide more detailed information about the nature of the `NullPointerException`. Could you please try again and paste the contents of the error log?

Comment: error log is clean, i only get "Wed Feb 23 10:20:48 EET 2011:INFO:Got response for [memberserviceSOAP.GetMemberDetails:Request 1] in 73ms (1079 bytes)
" in soapUI log, but the response i get is apache/tomcat 404

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and haven't found a solution yet either.

Comment: Verify that the case of your _localPart_ is coherent with your xsd element's name.

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that your @PayloadRoot initializers are correct. My "localpart" definition did not match the element name in the XSD. here is how my Java class looks now:

```
 @PayloadRoot(localPart = "GetLoginRequest", namespace = "<namespace>")
```

And here is the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="<namespace>" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="<namespace>">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="user-types.xsd"></xsd:include>

    <xsd:element name="GetLoginRequest" type="loginRequest"></xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="GetLoginReply" type="loginReply"></xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I played with this for an hour and this reply helped me find a typo in my namespace.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure SoapUI follows your URL mapping.
In my case, SoapUI did not automatically append ".wsdl" at the end.

in my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/HelloPersonService.wsdl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In Soap UI, the ".wsdl" was not there. Just add it manually in the address-bar like thing in Soap UI and proceed with your test.

Answer (score 0):

PayloadRoot namespace and schema namespace should be same

Answer (score 0):

Do a component scan on the package that contains all the endpoints. This worked for me. In memberservice-servlet.xml include the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bk.memberservice.endpoint" />
```